# MySQL error on pythonanywhere when trying to insert record

Tags: python, mysql, pythonanywhere

I'm getting a strange error when I try to register a record on pythonanywhere MySQL.

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())', (username, salt, hashed, email,token,plan,))
```

Locally it runs fine.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
    `id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `salt` varchar(29) NOT NULL,
    `pw_hash` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(320) NOT NULL,
    `token` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `plan` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `last_payment` date DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define the columns your inserting into:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO accounts(username, salt, pw_hash, email, token, plan, last_payment) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())", (username, salt, hashed, email, token, plan))
```

No need to add a NULL value for `id` here - you've defined it as `NOT NULL` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which means MySQL will populate that value for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your tuple has a  comma too much.

simply remove it

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())', (username, salt, hashed, email,token,plan))
```